# Debugging Dockerized Django Application Using PyCharm

Tags: django, docker, debugging, terminal, pycharm

I'm running a dockerized Django application using the Mac terminal and then trying to debug it using PyCharm. Is it possible to do this or do I have to run the application from within PyCharm for it to be available for debugging? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If  you want to use PyCharm for debugging then it will be good to configure Docker as a remote interpreter in PyCharm and start running Django.

Reference : https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/using-docker-as-a-remote-interpreter.html